# null values after supabase gen types command

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, types, supabase-database

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2BkIs.png)

I am trying to generate types for typescript project and I am connected to [Supabase](https://supabase.com/).
Database has tables, and thus a schema, yet after running the command below, the *supabase.ts* file gets filled with null (`NUL`) as in the image.

```
npx supabase gen types typescript --project-id myprojectid --schema public > src/types/supabase.ts
```

Can someone provide a solution?

Comment: Welcome. Please indicate what research you did before asking here, as this coud help getting answers. Related? https://github.com/orgs/supabase/discussions/5432

Comment: What output do you expect? [mre] ?